# Netgear M4100-50G routing issues

Tags: routing, vlan, netgear

I configured a Netgear M4100-50G to route between its vlans and the rest of the network (VLAN 1).

So far so good. Here's the setup:

[image: Network Dia]

As seen in the diagram, it is possible to ping the VLAN2 device from a VLAN1 device. However, same procedure just vice versa is impossible. Connection to the internet is working from VLAN2.

So a VLAN2 device is able to ping the gateway and go to the internet but it is impossible to ping any device on the gateways subnet (except the gateway).

All firewalls have been disabled on the VLAN1 devices in order to test.

Comment: If the device in VLAN1 has a static route back to VLAN2 it works.
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The Internet-Gateway had a filter for asymmetric routing enabled. Disabling this fixes all issues.